editing fstab with different mount point for raid array
I created a software raid 5 array on ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I mistakenly created a mount point it seems called "/mnt/mdo" instead of "/md0"
I mean, to be fair it probably really doesnt matter, but i would prefer it to be "md0"
my line in fstab looks like this
"/dev/md0 /mnt/mdo ext4 defaults,nofail,discard o o"
I have an exisiting folder structure already in /mnt/md0/"folder_1/"
that I had created thinking the array was mounted in md0
Anywho, can i just edit the fstab file and replace "/mnt/mdo" with "/mnt/md0"?
or would that break it, and if so, would it be better to unmout the drive, delete the existing folders, recreate them, and then redo the mount point?

unless someone else suggests to the contrary, I would be tempted to first copy the offending line in fstab, edit it to what you require and then edit the original out out with # as the first character in the line  whilst being ready with a live USB to boot back in to the system to put it back as it was if it breaks it. Other than that, leave it as it is as it's only cosmetic.

If '/mnt/md0' exists then a simple edit of fstab will work if you only change /mdo to /md0
